# Неполучается сгруппировать

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос, firebird

Доброе время суток,
Есть таблица,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сформирована (из двух таблиц посредством запроса) , мне нужно
Сгруппировать ее по полю *FIELD1*, так чтобы в первом столбике отобрались данные *FIELD1*, во втором столбце суммарное количество четных и нечетных чисел для каждого из значений в *FIELD1*, а в третьем тип (отрицательное/положительное число)

Желаемый результат:

```
FIELD1       FIELD2      FIELD3
AU            1          положительное
AU            2          отрицательное
DUSD          1          положительное
FJ            1          положительное
RG            1          отрицательное
RJ            1          положительное
SD            1          положительное
SD            1          отрицательное
PJ            2          отрицательное
GB            1          отрицательное
US            1          отрицательное
DM            2          положительное
UU            1          отрицательное
```

И отсортированное от больших «положительных» к отрицательным, т.е. по FIELD2

Результат №2

```
FIELD1       FIELD2      FIELD3           FIELD4      FIELD5 
AU            1          положительное     2          отрицательное
DUSD          1          положительное     null       отрицательное
PJ           null        положительное     2          отрицательное
...
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `суммарное количество четных и нечетных чисел` Для вещественных чисел понятие чётности не определено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FIELD1,
       COUNT(1),
       CASE WHEN MAX(FIELD2) >= 0 THEN 'положительное' ELSE 'отрицательное' END
  FROM table
 GROUP BY FIELD1,
          CASE WHEN FIELD2 >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 ORDER BY MAX(FIELD2) DESC
```

Как то так, если нулей заведомо нет или их надо выделять отдельно (так как они не отрицательны и не положительны), то в группировке можно воспользоваться функцией [`sign()`](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-sign.html). Что означает "отсортировать от больших field2 к меньшим" в условиях группировки совершенно не ясно, предположил, что надо взять максимальное field2 для группы, правда порядок при этом не будет соответствовать тому, что вы привели в примере. В вашем примере вообще не ясен порядок сортировки.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, а не подскажите еще одно по этому запросу, как сделать, чтоб отрицательные значения (Field3) с cоответствующими ему Field2, отобразить в 4-м и 5 столбце (если в field1 есть одинаковые значения). Т.к. например в Field1 есть значения например "AU" (ни одинаковые и положительное и отрицательное). мне бы хотелось такие значения свести в одну строку, А то я *case* переделал, но получились дополнительные столбцы (как я и хотел), но все равно разнесенные по типу (положительные/отрицательные). А в место несуществующих значений (field2) ставить *null*

Comment: @Konstantin78 `select FIELD1, sum(CASE WHEN FIELD2 >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as positive, sum(CASE WHEN FIELD2 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as negative from table group by FIELD1`

Comment: спасибо.........

Answer (score 0):

Если ориентироваться на пример, а не на текст (т.е. нужно количество положительных/отрицательных), то

```
SELECT FIELD1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN FIELD2 >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FIELD2
     , 'положительное' FIELD3
FROM data_table
UNION ALL
SELECT FIELD1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN FIELD2 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     , 'отрицательное'
FROM data_table
```

> отсортированное от больших «положительных» к отрицательным

Фраза непонятна. Возможно, потребуется добавить нечто вроде

```
ORDER BY 1, 2
```